# Неправильно написана 5 строка кода, но в каком моменте?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```py
import re , pyperclip

text=str(pyperclip.paste())

found=re.compile(r'((\+7|8)\d{10})([a-zA-Z0-9._&+-]+@(g)?mail\.(com|ru)',re.DOTALL).findall(text)

pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(found))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Высший класс:

-привести код из ЧЕТЫРЕХ строчек.

-соизволить сообщить, что ошибка в ПЯТОЙ строчке.

-великодушно позволить другим разобраться, "в каком моменте" у вас ошибка. При этом умолчать даже о том, что за ошибка возникла.

Отвечаю в стиле вашего вопроса. Вот в этом *моменте*:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._&+-]+@(g)?mail\.(com|ru)
```

И, кстати, интерпретатор об этом вам совершенно ясно и однозначно сказал:

```
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern
```